# Foreign key of foreign key in django-polymorphic

Tags: django, django-polymorphic

I have the following (simplified) `django` and `django-polymorphic` models:

```
class GenericOffer(PolymorphicModel):
    pass
class OfferA(GenericOffer):
    special = models.IntegerField()
class OfferB(GenericOffer):
    pass

class GenericProduct(PolymorphicModel):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(to=GenericOffer)
class ProductA(GenericProduct):
    pass
class ProductB(GenericProduct):
    pass

class Gizmo(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=GenericProduct)
```

from which I can create the following instances:

```
offer_a = OfferA()
product_a = ProductA(offer=offer_a)
gizmo_a = Gizmo(product=product_a)
```

Now, I have:

```
assert product_a.offer == offer_a
assert gizmo_a.product == product_a
```

But:

```
assert gizmo_a.product_a.offer != offer_a
assert gizmo_a.product_a.offer.get_real_instance() == offer_a
```

That is, the foreign key linked to a foreign key of my `Gizmo` is not automatically cast to its proper type.

- Is it the expected behavior?
- Should I use a `GenericRelation` instead of a `ForeignKey` in my `Gizmo` ?

Thanks for any advice